# IIS 7.5 response generation time

Tags: asp.net, iis, networking, iis-7

I've got two log files.
The first one is made by my asp.net application.
The second is made by IIS.

The problem is that request processing time which is logged by my asp.net application is significantly differs from the time_taken which is logged by IIS

> According to the
>   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloc/2008/07/20/time-taken-and-logparser-for-web-site-statistics/
>
> Beginning in IIS 6.0, the time-taken field typically includes network
>   time. Before HTTP.sys logs the value in the time-taken field, HTTP.sys
>   usually waits for the client to acknowledge the last response packet
>   send operation or HTTP.sys waits for the client to reset the
>   underlying TCP connection. Therefore, when a large response or large
>   responses are sent to a client over a slow network connection, the
>   value of the time-taken field may be more than expected.

Is it possible to know whether the problem is caused by network delays or it took much time to put a request from request queue into the asp.net application?